# How do you convert JSON to an ES6 Map?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I'm trying to convert JSON of the form:

```
{1: 1, 4: -1}
```

to a `Map` where the keys are of type integer.

I managed to do this:

```
  let myMap = new Map(Object.entries(payload));
```

but it ends up converting the keys to strings.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In a JSON string, the keys are a string. If you are using `Object.entries`, it means its an `Object`

Comment: Object keys are always strings.

Comment: Where is the JSON string?

Comment: I figured that much out; what I wasn't able to figure out is how to get it to convert it to a Map with integer keys.

Comment: are you using `JSON.parse` if so you can use the `reviver` option.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can convert the strings to numbers.

```
const myMap = new Map(Object.entries(payload).map(([k, v]) => ([+k, v]) ));
```

Comment: This is the solution! Thank you! :)

Comment: @cjm2671 It is my pleasure.